# Switch statement for imported NS_OPTIONS (RawOptionSetType) in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, enumeration

The switch statement in Swift is so much more expressive. I'm wondering if this might be possible:

Lets look at UIViewAutoresizing for example. It's defined in Objective-C as follows:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIViewAutoresizing) {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
```

I can use it in Swift like an enum:

```
let foo = UIViewAutoresizing([.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleTopMargin])
```

Is it possible to use a switch statement instead of multiple if-statements?

```
if foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight != nil {

}

if foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth != nil {

}

if foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin != nil {

}
```

Something like this pseudo code:

```
switch foo { // ** THIS IS PSEUDO CODE AND WILL NOT COMPILE **

case & .FlexibleHeight:
    println("height")

case & .FlexibleWidth:
    println("width")

case & .FlexibleTop:
    println("top")

}
```

Comment: case let value where value & .FlexibleHeight != nil: but it's still not good enough

Comment: the `if-else` statement doesn't make much sense for bit masked values like shown above, as it will stop for the first found non-null bit, but an variable make hold several options and there for several non-null bits.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you're right. I wanted to express something else. See changes.

Comment: Your `if` cascade isn't actually an `if`-`else` cascade like you say, but rather a sequence of independent conditionals. This is a good thing, though, because as @vikingosegundo notes, a value of this type can have multiple flags set. Using a `switch` statement here would hurt, not help you — pattern matching is for *mutually exclusive* options only.

Comment: Ok, not the best question, but we are all new to swift. In a switch statement exactly one case statement gets executed. See my answer below, for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was frustrated enough about this problem that I wrote a `Bitmask<T>` class that can handle these use cases.  The code is up on Github: [brynbellomy/SwiftBitmask](https://github.com/brynbellomy/SwiftBitmask)

It allows you to do stuff like this with any kind of object as your underlying type (here I'm using an `enum`):

```
enum MonsterAttributes : IBitmaskRepresentable, IAutoBitmaskable {
    case Big, Ugly, Scary

    static var autoBitmaskValues : [MonsterAttributes] = [.Big, .Ugly, .Scary,]
    var  bitmaskValue: UInt16  { return AutoBitmask..autoBitmaskValueFor(self) }
    init(bitmaskValue: UInt16) { self = AutoBitmask.autoValueFromBitmask(bitmaskValue) }
}

// various ways to initialize
let option : MonsterAttributes = .Ugly

let bitmaskOfOption        = Bitmask(option)
let anotherBitmaskOfOption = |MonsterAttributes.Ugly // same as bitmaskOfOption

let orWithVar = option | .Big                 // == Bitmask<MonsterAttributes> with a bitmaskValue of 1 | 2
let simpleOr  = MonsterAttributes.Big | .Ugly // == Bitmask<MonsterAttributes> with a bitmaskValue of 1 | 2

// getting the raw integral bitmask value
let simpleOrValue = simpleOr.bitmaskValue                        // == UInt16(1 | 2)
let orValue       = (MonsterAttributes.Big | .Ugly).bitmaskValue // == UInt16(1 | 2)

// implements BooleanType
if simpleOr & .Ugly             { /* this code will execute */ }

// supports pattern matching operator
if simpleOr ~= .Ugly            { /* this code will execute */ }
if simpleOr ~= (.Ugly | .Scary) { /* this code will execute */ }
```

... and all you have to do is implement a one-property protocol.

I'm really curious if anyone has any feedback on or ideas for the code, so please leave an issue in the queue if you think of anything!

Answer (score 1):

I tried several hours yesterday and today to make this work with switch — no success.

The reason is that in this particular case we need to test against several cases. In Swift we need to use the `fallthrough` key word. But we are not allowed to fall through to the next case if that next case uses a variable, there for we cannot use the `case let where` statement, as shown here:

```
switch foo {
case let x where x & .FlexibleHeight != nil:
    println("height")
case let x where x & .FlexibleWidth != nil:
    println("width")
case let x where x & .FlexibleTopMargin != nil:
    println("top margin")
default:
    println("no")
}
```

This will break out once a case triggered. But

```
switch foo {
case let x where x & .FlexibleHeight != nil:
    println("height")
    fallthrough

case let x where x & .FlexibleWidth != nil:
    println("width")
    fallthrough

case let x where x & .FlexibleTopMargin != nil:
    println("top margin")
default:
    println("no")
}
```

does not work for the reason described above.

---

I'd go with a clear if statement, like

```
let foo = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

let width = foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
let height = foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

if width == .FlexibleWidth {
    println("width")
}

if height == .FlexibleHeight {
    println("height")
}
```

or

```
let foo = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

let usesFlexibleWidth = (foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth) != nil;
let usesFlexibleHeight = (foo & UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight) != nil;

if usesFlexibleWidth {
    println("width")
}

if usesFlexibleHeight {
    println("height")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can, although it's a little more convoluted now that `RawOptionSetType` doesn't implement the `BooleanType` protocol.

```
switch foo {
case let x where x & .FlexibleHeight != nil:
    println("height")
case let x where x & .FlexibleWidth != nil:
    println("width")
case let x where x & .FlexibleTopMargin != nil:
    println("top margin")
default:
    println("no")
}
```

Note that this stops on the first condition that matches! So it really is another form of this:

```
if foo & .FlexibleHeight != nil {
    println("height")
} else if foo & .FlexibleWidth != nil {
    println("width")
} else if foo & .FlexibleTopMargin != nil {
    println("top margin")
}
```

Comment: Stopping on first match means it is a useless solution for an NS_OPTIONS. You would need the `fallthrough` keyword or you would need to stick to the multiple `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I came up with is this:

```
let foo = /* .. your value to test .. */

let allCases = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin]

for oneCase in allCases {
    switch oneCase & foo {

    case UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight:
        println("height")

    case UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth:
        println("width")

    case UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin:
        println("top")

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably working, but not an elegant solution to loop like that. I would recommend to seek a solution with the `fallthrough` keyword or stick to multiple `if`.