# MCOMessageFlag in Swift

Tags: macos, mailcore2

I am trying to check message flags, in Swift but am not getting anywhere. I have been referring to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388065/switch-statement-for-imported-ns-options-rawoptionsettype-in-swift) for help.

Inside a `fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder` I am getting a selection of messages, seen, flagged, etc.. when I check them, no flags are reported

```
let requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Headers
let uids = MCOIndexSet(range: MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX))
let folder = "INBOX"

let fetchOperation = self.imapSession.fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder(folder, requestKind: requestKind, uids: uids)

fetchOperation.start { (error, fetchedMessages, vanishedMessages) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        println("Error: \(error)")
    } else {
        for obj in fetchedMessages {
            if let message = obj as? MCOIMAPMessage {

                let messageSeen = (message.flags & MCOMessageFlag.Seen) != nil;
                let messageFlagged = (message.flags & MCOMessageFlag.Flagged) != nil;

                if messageSeen {
                    println("Seen")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I manually set the flags Seen and Flagged are printed as expected..

```
message.flags = MCOMessageFlag.Seen | MCOMessageFlag.Flagged

let messageSeen = (message.flags & MCOMessageFlag.Seen) != nil;
let messageFlagged = (message.flags & MCOMessageFlag.Flagged) != nil;

if messageSeen {
    println("Seen")
}
...
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any pointers?

Comment: To get flags, you probably need to use `let requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Headers | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Flags`.

Comment: That was it, I feel stupid I didn't realise that. I even checked the other request kinds, I must have skipped straight past flags. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Dinh Viêt Hoà suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180512/mcomessageflag-in-swift#comment42852035_27180512), the fetchOperation request headers needed to include the flags.

```
let requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Headers | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Flags
let uids = MCOIndexSet(range: MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX))
let folder = "INBOX"

let fetchOperation = self.imapSession.fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder(folder, requestKind: requestKind, uids: uids)
```