# Is there a better way to check active notification settings?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Is there a better way in Swift to check if a specific flag is set on `application.currentUserNotificationSettings().types`?

For example how would you check if the application is allow to update it's badge?

Below is the current method I'm using, but I thought there might be a better way in Swift, like some operator I don't know about.

```
func printUserNotificationSettings() {
    println("Notification Settings:")
    let notificationSettingsTypes = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().types
    let badgeOn: Bool = (notificationSettingsTypes & UIUserNotificationType.Badge) == UIUserNotificationType.Badge
    let soundOn: Bool = (notificationSettingsTypes & UIUserNotificationType.Sound) == UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let alertOn: Bool = (notificationSettingsTypes & UIUserNotificationType.Alert) == UIUserNotificationType.Alert

    println("\tBadge? \(badgeOn)")
    println("\tSound? \(soundOn)")
    println("\tAlert? \(alertOn)")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only thing you can do to improve the code is make it more concise.

```
func printUserNotificationSettings() {
    println("Notification Settings:")
    let notificationSettingsTypes = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().types
    let badgeOn = (notificationSettingsTypes & .Badge) != nil
    let soundOn = (notificationSettingsTypes & .Sound) != nil
    let alertOn = (notificationSettingsTypes & .Alert) != nil

    println("\tBadge? \(badgeOn)")
    println("\tSound? \(soundOn)")
    println("\tAlert? \(alertOn)")
}
```

`UIUserNotificationType` implements `RawOptionSetType` which is the swift mapping from `NS_OPTIONS` in Objective C code. In earlier betas of Xcode, these objects also implemented `BooleanType`, which would have allowed you to write this code a little more concisely, but that seems to have been removed prior to release.

Also, searching around, the most common way to do the check is `!= nil` so I have included that modification as well, it seems to improve the readability a bit.

Here is a pretty robust StackOverflow post on the topic: [Switch statement for imported NS_OPTIONS (RawOptionSetType) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388065/switch-statement-for-imported-ns-options-rawoptionsettype-in-swift)

And another great article on the background of RawOptionSetType: http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype/